# Can you explain to me, in what months are the futures and options on gold and silver listed, based on the CME description?

Tags: options, futures, commodities, online-trading, precious-metals

I read the following contract specifications from CME and couldn't figure out/understand it.
On Gold;
Futures: Monthly contracts listed for 3 consecutive months, any Feb, Apr, Aug, Oct in the nearest 23 months and any Jun and Dec in the nearest 72 months.
Options: Monthly contracts listed for 20 consecutive months and any June in December in the nearest 72 months.

On Silver;
Futures: Monthly contracts listed for 3 consecutive months and any Jan, Mar, May, and Sep in the nearest 23 months and any Jul and Dec in the nearest 60 months.
Options: Monthly contracts listed for 6 consecutive months, 3 months of March, May and September and any July and December in the nearest 60 months

Comment: could you give a specific example you want explained? like "GC12" or whatever?

Comment: I know that's not a short explanation, but it's accurate - the months that have listed futures/options changes as time goes on - what specifically are you confused about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The months that have listed futures and options change as time goes on, so that description is accurate.

For example, it's currently June. So there should be Gold futures for July, August, September of this year (3 consecutive months). Then for October of this year, and February and April of next year (the nearest 23 months), Then for December of this year, June and December of the next 5 years, and June 2027 (nearest 72 months).

Putting all of that in a list, as of today you'd get futures contracts for:

- Jul 2021
- Aug 2021
- Sep 2021
- Oct 2021
- Dec 2021
- Feb 2022
- Apr 2022
- Jun 2022
- Dec 2022
- Jun 2023
- Dec 2023
- Jun 2024

...

- Jun 2027

Next month, Jul 2021 would drop off ("expire") but no contracts will be added (since Oct 2021 is already active). The month after that, Aug 2021 will expire and Nov 2021 and Aug 2022 will be added